# How to choose most recent date path from list of strings?

Tags: python

Say that we have the following paths in string format from S3:

```
ldata_snshots/11-11-2021/
ldata_snshots/12-11-2021/
```

What function would we need to return `ldata_snshots/12-11-2021/` as our latest string path?

The date format is `dd-mm-yyyy`

I have tried:

```
dates = []
for x in lst_of_str:
    dates.append(x.split("ldata_snshots/",1)[1])
```

Then I tried to do a max on that but for some reason it was failing...

Comment: Is that `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yy`?

Comment: haha the former ;)

Comment: @JaapVersteegh why would you give them the solution then? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi 'Them' has a name btw

Comment: @SuzanAydın downvotes are reversible after editing. Also, upvoting out of pity defeats the purpose of having a voting system. If a question doesn't show research effort, it deserves all the downvotes it gets.

Answer (score 3):

Use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to extract a `datetime.datetime` object -- datetimes are comparable, so you can then use functions like `max` and `sort` with that datetime as a `key`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> paths = ["ldata_snshots/11-11-2021/", "ldata_snshots/12-11-2021/"]
>>> max(paths, key=lambda p: datetime.datetime.strptime(p, "ldata_snshots/%d-%m-%Y/"))
'ldata_snshots/12-11-2021/'
```

Comment: I like.... I likey a lot...

Comment: Perfect :) - i'll try it out

Comment: should be `%m` instead of `%M` right?

Comment: lol yes, I can never remember offhand.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from os import path
from datetime import datetime

def latest(strs): 
    d = {datetime.strptime(path.dirname(s).split('/')[-1], '%d-%m-%Y'): s for s in strs} 
    return d[sorted(d)[-1]] 


print(f"Latest: {latest(['ldata_snshots/12-11-2021/', 'ldata_snshots/11-11-2021/'])}")
```